# How to print on more than one printer at the same time the same PDF file

Tags: java, android

How can i print the same PDF file `on more than one printer at the same time`?

Printers are connected at the same LAN.

I need to integrate in my app a method...

please give s solution,Thanks in Advance?

Answer (score 1):

Start another Thread and ask this Thread to print at the same time of the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android 4.4+ printing framework, there is no option for this. You can print the document twice, but the user chooses the printer.

If you are not using the Android 4.4+ printing framework, contact your printer manufacturer for support.

Comment: now i create and open PDF with hpEprint to print PDF.....but in this way user must select printer.....:(